# This is a probability question once asked in gate exam can anyone please solve this

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Subway trains on a certain line runs every half hour between midnight and six in the morning. What is the probability that the men entering the station at random time during the period will have to wait at least 20 minutes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's no trick or technique required to solve this. Just think about the situation being described. If you enter the station at 2:05, how long do you wait for the 2:30 train? What fraction of possible entry times result in a wait time of at least 20 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

The wait time will be a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 30]$, meaning $f(x) = \frac{1}{30}$. A man will have to wait at least $20$ minutes if he arrives at a time in the interval $[0, 10]$, meaning the probability would be
$$\int_{0}^{10}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{10}\frac{1}{30}dx = \frac{1}{3}$$